# only single gradle sub-project among multiple sub-projects can resolve symbols from a shared sourceset folder in intellj

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I am working on a gradle project which has multiple sub-projects. To simplify the problem description, I am using a simple project here.

The project structure looks like

```
/client-v1
    /src
        /main
            /java
                /v1
                    Client.java
    build.gradle

/client-v2/
    /src
        /main
            /java
                /v2
                    Client.java  
    build.gradle
/common
    /src
        /main
            /java
                /common
                    Util.java
settings.gradle
```

client-v1 and client-v2 are sub-projects and /common is a sourceSet folder. The settings.gradle is

```
rootProject.name = 'client'

include('client-v1', 'client-v2')
```

The build.gradle in client-v1 and client-v2 has the sourceSet definition as below.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir '../common/src/main/java'
        }
    }
}
```

`gradle build` works fine in project root, client-v1 folder and client-v2 folder. Also my vscode resolves all the symbols in client-v1, client-v2, and common.

Here is the problem. However, in Intellij-idea(IntelliJ Community 2021.1), client-v2 doesn't recognize the Common symbol whereas client-v2 does.

For example,

```
package client.v1;


import common.Util; // Okay

...
```

```
package client.v2;


import common.Util; // Cannot resolve symbol 'Util'
...
```

So, I updated the settings.gradle to remove the client-v1 as below:

```
rootProject.name = 'client'

include('client-v2')
```

Then the `Cannot resolve symbol 'Util'` error messages in client-v2's Client.java disappears in intellj.

So it seems like that the intellij enables only single gradle project to resolve symbols from a sourceSet. Is it true? Is there any way to address the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is a limitation of the IDE: [IDEA-214527](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-214527) *Two modules in a project cannot share the same content root*.